# Using a font stack for a java TextField rather than a single font

Tags: java, fonts

I have 2 textfields, where the first is for English text, and the second is for non-English text (Khmer). This works just fine, but I also need a third TextField that should be able to render both English *and* Khmer.

The problem is that if I set the font for third TextField to either of the ones I use, text will only render for either English, or Khmer. For instance, for Khmer I use the following code:

```
this.f = Font.createFont( Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("D:\\java\\Khmer.ttf") );
f = f.deriveFont(12f);
```

(Khmer font used: http://www.selapa.net/khmerfonts/fontinfo.php?font=2)

But this font cannot render English text. Is there a way to use multiple physical fonts in a way that Java treats it as a single logical font, so that I can use that with my TextField?